# Is there a way to make an empty schema with column names from a list?

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to make an empty PySpark dataframe in the case where it didn't exist before. I also have a list of column names. Is it possible to define an empty PySpark dataframe without manual assignment?

I have a list of columns `final_columns`, which I can use to select a subset of columns from a dataframe. However, in the case when this dataframe doesn't exist, I would like to create an empty dataframe with the same columns in `final_columns`. I would like to do this without manually assigning the names.

```python
final_columns = ['colA', 'colB', 'colC', 'colD', 'colE']

try:
    sdf = sqlContext.table('test_table')
except: 
    print("test_table is empty")
    mySchema = StructType([ StructField("colA", StringType(), True),
                            StructField("colB", StringType(), True),
                            StructField("colC", StringType(), True),
                            StructField("colD", StringType(), True),
                            StructField("colE", DoubleType(), True) ])
    sdf = sqlContext.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD(),schema=mySchema)

sdf = sdf.select(final_columns)
```

Comment: you can loop over the names, but you'll need to have a list of the datatypes as well. how are we supposed to know that `colE` is the only one that's not a string?

Comment: We don't know that, but good to know to loop over the names. I will create the empty dataframe with loops, and then manually pick out to change the type for the specific columns. Thank you!